# Is it exist better way to emplement lock/unlock button with swiftui?

Tags: button, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-button

I tried to implement lock/unlock button, but it was hard to make.
In my case, I used two Image. One is Rectangle with a lock, another is just a rectangle.
And using ZStack, made them as a one button.

```
// mincho

import SwiftUI                                                                  
struct ZStackView: View {
var clearInfoData : ClearInfo
var body: some View {
    ZStack{
        NavigationLink(destination: HonorDetailView(clearInfo: clearInfoData).toolbar{
            Button(action: {
        }, label: {
            Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
        })
        }) {
            Image(clearInfoData.clearImage)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        }.zIndex(data) // when stage cleared, data will change 0 to 1. 
            Image("LockedRectangle")
    }
}

struct ZStackView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    ZStackView(clearInfoData: cleardata[0].clearInfo[1])
}
```

}

Like this, Image + NavigationLink -> as a Button.
So when stage cleared, this button show unlock image and working navigation view.
And I want to control button's opacity when it clicked.

In my guess, button's opacity going lower when i click.
However I want that button keep opaque.

1. Is it exist other better way to make unlock/lock button?
2. If it is best way, what should I do to make this button opaque?

Comment: Where and how is declared data ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.